# Query regarding HTTP headers and HTTP response status

Tags: rest, http

I am trying to build a REST service and I have a few questions.

1. When I send `Location` header is body required?
2. `If-modified-since`: Can this header value be `null` or not set to indicate whatever latest version in `PUT` and `DELETE` calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No, the `Location` header does not require body content. In fact, if the status code of the response is `302 Found` or a similar redirect, body content would make no sense.
2. The header `If-modified-since` is part of the HTTP concept 'Conditional GET'. If it is not set and if not other header that is part of this concept (`If-Match`, `If-None-Match`, `If-Unmodified-Since`) is set, the server is supposed to return a representation of the current resource.

In fact, Conditional GET is not a concept about versions but about caching. If the client already knows a representation of the resource that is still up-to-date, it would be redundand for the server to return the same representation again.